# While using ImageIO.read in java I get input == null

Tags: java

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/CkD6485J

When I run it through I get an input == null! error and I marked all the places the error was caused by. I put the /res/ folder in the build path and it didnt work. I tried removing it, and putting it back in, and I tried removing the /res from the file location. I'm also following this from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLhUzuTSTAc so I'm not sure why it won't work.

Comment: Euh, did you add the files as resources in the jar?

Comment: What happens if you specify `res/` instead of `/res`?

Comment: The code must be posted *here.*

Answer (score 0):

The resource `/res/sheet.png` should be in the same jar as the  GameComponent.class` file. Also the path is case-sensitive. Open the jar with 7zip, WinZip or whatever and inspect the path.

It might be, that it should have been `/sheet.png`, when all below `/res` is added to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about this but after a few days of of looking it over i figured out that there was something wrong with the .png file I used for my resource. I downloaded a completely new one and it works fine. Thanks for the ideas though